# Is there a way to pass a prop to the main component in dioxus?

Tags: rust, dioxus

I recently started writing UIs in dioxus and have a big struct that is passed to different components. I do not have full control over that struct as it is from a third-party library. This struct cannot cannot be `const` and can therefore not be global. It has to be initiated in `main`. A simplified example might look like this:

```rust
use dioxus::prelude::*;

#[derive(Props)]
struct BigStructWrapper<'a> {
    s: &'a mut BigStruct,
}

#[allow(non_snake_case)]
fn App<'a>(cx: Scope<'a, BigStructWrapper<'a>>) -> Element {
    cx.render(rsx! {
        div {
            // Something with BigStructWrapper/BigStruct
        }
    })
}

fn main() {
    let big_struct = BigStructWrapper {
        s: &mut BigStruct::new(),
    };

    dioxus_desktop::launch(App);
}
```

I then get the error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:40:28
   |
31 |     dioxus_desktop::launch(App);
   |     ---------------------- ^^^ expected fn pointer, found fn item
   |     |
   |     arguments to this function are incorrect
   |
   = note: expected fn pointer `for<'a> fn(&'a Scoped<'a>) -> Option<VNode<'a>>`
                 found fn item `for<'a> fn(&'a Scoped<'a, BigStructWrapper<'a>>) -> Option<VNode<'a>> {
```

Is there a workaround to allow this? Is there a more proper way to do this without a wrapper struct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is described in the [Sharing State](https://dioxuslabs.com/docs/0.3/guide/en/interactivity/sharing_state.html) section of the dioxus documentation. You handle state in dioxus with functions such as [`use_state`](https://docs.rs/dioxus/latest/dioxus/prelude/fn.use_state.html) or [`use_ref`](https://docs.rs/dioxus/latest/dioxus/prelude/fn.use_ref.html). Here a small example with `use_state` where we create the `BigStruct` instance in our `App` and pass it down to other components:

```rust
#![allow(non_snake_case)]

use dioxus::prelude::*;

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
struct BigStruct;

impl BigStruct {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Self
    }
}

fn App(cx: Scope) -> Element {
    let big_struct = use_state(cx, || BigStruct::new());

    cx.render(rsx! {
        Element { bs: big_struct }
    })
}

#[inline_props]
fn Element<'a>(cx: Scope, bs: &'a BigStruct) -> Element {
    cx.render(rsx! {
      div {
        "hello {bs:?}"
      }
    })
}

fn main() {
    dioxus_desktop::launch(App);
}
```

Comment: This is one solution, but I think I will rather try to either make the instance of `BigStruct` global using `lazy_static` or make a function that always returns the same instance. I will maybe see in the future that your solution will reduce the code complexity.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try passing the struct directly over main by using `launch_with_props()`:

```
fn main() {
    let big_struct = BigStructWrapper {
        s: &mut BigStruct::new(),
    };

    dioxus_desktop::launch_with_props(App, big_struct, Config::new())
}
```

From there, you should be able to access it in the component thru `cx.props.s`.